# FirebaseMessagingService doesn't restart after device reboot or after app is killed from system tray

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am using `FirebaseMessagingService` to send push notifications to my Pocophone X3 NFC. However, I will send a notification token and erase the notification token from my Firestore database first when logging in and logging out happens. This is to ensure that the notification is sent to the correct user.

To do the above, I have the following code.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MessagingService :
    FirebaseMessagingService(),
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
    @Inject
    lateinit var notificationRepository: NotificationRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(this)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val title = remoteMessage.notification?.title
        val message = remoteMessage.notification?.body
        if (message != null && title != null) {
            sendPushNotification(title, message)
        }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        saveTokenToSharedPreferences(token)
        authRepository.getUser()?.let {
            val uid = it.uid
            sendTokenToFirestore(uid, token)
        }
    }

    override fun onAuthStateChanged(auth: FirebaseAuth) {
        auth.currentUser?.let {
            val uid = it.uid
            val savedRegistrationToken =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                    .getString(getString(R.string.fcm_token_shared_pref_key), "")
            savedRegistrationToken?.let { token -> sendTokenToFirestore(uid, token) }
        }
    }

    private fun sendPushNotification(title: String, messageBody: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val channelId = getString(R.string.general_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mlearn_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            getString(R.string.general_notification_channel_name),
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    private fun saveTokenToSharedPreferences(token: String) {
        val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        with (sharedPref.edit()) {
            putString(getString(R.string.fcm_token_shared_pref_key), token)
            apply()
        }
    }

    private fun sendTokenToFirestore(uid: String, token: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            notificationRepository.sendNotificationToken(uid, token)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_CODE = 0
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 0
    }
}
```

I also registered the service to the manifest like so.

```
        <service
          android:name=".service.MessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

The code is working fine *when I install the app for the first time and if I don't do any device restarts or app killing*. However, when I either

- turn off my phone and turn it back on; or
- kill the app from my recent apps list

the `FirebaseMessagingService` code will no longer run. As a result, when I do log in using a new account, the new account does not have the notification token associated with it because the service isn't running.

How do I make `FirebaseMessagingService` keep running even on app kills and phone turning off and turning on (i.e. restarts)? Note that the app installed is not signed yet.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your service

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

also, it takes some time to receive FCM messages after restart, that doesnt mean your service isnt running. If you start receiving messages after like 5 mins of restart that means your service is working fine, it just takes some time for new tokens to register

if all else fails, check out this project's implementation of FCM, its solid, restarts automatically and saves tokens to firebase

https://github.com/yahyakhan234/PharmaGO2-master